# How to repaint list in extjs?

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have the following list:

```
Ext.define('MyList', {
    extend: 'Ext.List',
    store: mystore,

    //and others properties.....    

});
```

Can I repaint my list on the page, when I added new data in `mystore`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved when I used [loadData](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-loadData) method